# soy nuevo en php SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046

Tags: php, mysqldb, exec

[![][1]][1]

estoy aprendiendo usar php , pude logre conectar una base de datos con éxito  con xampp a través de mysql. Lo siguiente que hice fue intentar insertar contenido a mi tabla creada en mi base de datos

cree una variable $sql inserte los datos correspondiente y después con la función ->exec quise mandar los datos y me sale este error:

> ,Conexion erroneaPDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name:
> 1046 No database selected in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\curso-php-2022\ejercicio28.php:15 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\curso-php-2022\ejercicio28.php(15): PDO->exec('INSERT
> INTO `fo...') #1 {main}

Cree una variable $sql inserte los datos correspondiente y después con la función ->exec quise mandar los datos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sencillamente el problema está en que no seleccionas ninguna base de datos con la que tratar la información, eso te explica el error. Asegurate que seleccionas una base de datos. Accede [aquí](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-connect-php-to-mysql#:~:text=A%20PDO%20database%20connection%20requires,we%20stated%20inside%20the%20dbconfig.) para obtener más información. Se te ponen también unos ejemplos...

Comment: Prueba eliminando los espacios del [dsn](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) de PDO, es decir, **"mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=album"**.  Por cierto, no uses imágenes para agregar código a la pregunta, simplemente copia/pega el código, no todos pueden ver las imágenes desde sus dispositivos, gracias. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fijate que el new PDO debe ser asi

```
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=nombreDeTuBaseDeDatos", $usuario, $password);
```

Sacale los espacios que tenes en el medio y avisa si te funciona

La bd tiene ese nombre? existe?

Comment: Gracias de verdad!! , si tenias razon eran los espacios .me funciono perfecto.
Con respecto a la foto lo tomare en cuenta para la próxima consulta. saludos abrazo grande!!

Comment: Genial! Si te sirvio la respuesta, marcala como resuelta (hace clic en el tilde)